# How to convert in SQL the number of seconds into a human-readable duration?

Tags: sql, int, duration

In a SQL-database I make some selects, that get an duration (as result of a subtraction between two dates) in seconds as an int. But I want to format this result in a human-readable form like 'hh:mm' or 'dd:hh'. Is that possible in SQL and how can I realize this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL 2005, You can use the following:

```
    select convert(varchar(8), dateadd(second, [SecondsColumn], 0),  108)
```

Which first converts the seconds into a date after 1900-01-01, and then gets the hh:mm:ss part.

If the column is more than 24 hours, this will roll over, if you want days and then hours in that case just do something like:

```
case when SecondsColumn> (24*60*60) 
        then 
            cast(datepart(day,datediff(dd, 0, dateadd(second, SecondsColumn, 0))) as varchar(4))
        +   'd' + convert(varchar(2), dateadd(second, SecondsColumn, 0), 108) 
    else
            convert(varchar(8), dateadd(second, SecondsColumn, 0), 108) 
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Every database does it differently. I use PostgreSQL and it does it like so:

```
select to_char(my_date - my_other_date, 'HH:MM:SS');
```

You'll have to consult the manual for the database you are using.

Comment: The following works: select to_char(interval '1000s','HH24:MI:SS'); or select to_char(now()-pg_postmaster_start_time(),'DDD "days" HH24:MI:SS');

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have seconds:

```
DECLARE @DurationSeconds INT

-- 25h 45m 14s
SET @DurationSeconds = (25 * 3600) + (45 * 60) + (14)

SELECT 
  @DurationSeconds, 
  @DurationSeconds / 3600 hours, 
  @DurationSeconds % 3600 / 60 minutes,
  @DurationSeconds % (3600 / 60) seconds
```

I'll let the task of formatting that nicely to you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard, though many DBMSs have their own custom syntax.

In general it is better to be doing formatting-for-human-readability work in your application's presentation layer rather than anywhere near the database.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle SQL:

```
   -- 86,400 seconds in a  day
   --  3,600 seconds in an hour
   --     60 seconds in a  minute
   select duration, -- seconds
    trunc((duration)/86400) || ':' || -- dd
    trunc(mod(duration,86400)/3600) || ':' || -- hh
    trunc(mod(mod(duration,86400),3600)/60) || ':' || -- mm
    mod(mod(mod(duration,86400),3600),60) -- ss
   as human_readable
   from dual
   ;
```